# Container namespace isn't visible in ip netns list

Tags: 14.04, lxc, container

I wonder why we can't see the namespaces created by lxc-create on the output of "ip netns list"
For example I create a namespace like below

```
lxc-create -t download -n cont1 -- -d ubuntu -r trusty -a amd64
```

I don't see this on "ip netns list" however if I add a namespace myself,

```
root@lin:~# ip netns add test

root@lin:~# ip netns list
test
```

it is visible.

containers use namespaces but here namespaces created lxc-create are hidden from admin user? Is there any way to list them via ip netns?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the `lsns` command instead of `ip netns list`.

Answer (score 2):

The **ip netns list** command displays only namespaces that have been named, by virtue of a corresponding file in /var/run/netns/. Network namespaces can be created without names, though, and are referenced by a file descriptor. (The [ip-netns (8) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) mentions this.)

I believe lxc uses unnamed network namespaces. To see them, start a container and run **lsns -t net** .

Answer (score -1):

You cannot see LXC namespaces using ip netns.

LXCs use a different LXC can be listed by using

```
% sudo lxc-ls -f
```